# Regions of two curves

Tags: integration, area

The ratio of the areas of two regions of the curve $C_1 :4x^2+\pi^2y^2=4\pi^2$ divided by the curve
$C_2: y=-(\text{sgn}(x-\frac{\pi}{2}))\cos x $ (where $\text{sgn}$ denotes signum function) is______.

[image]

This is the diagram that I got through desmos.com.

The area of ellipse is $2\pi^2$.

Hence area above and below the $x-$axis is $\pi^2$. I don't know how to find the area of $D$. Because by using area under curve one must know the intersection point that I am not able to calculate.

Comment: Don't $D$'s cancel in terms of area?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. We've to find ratio of what?

Comment: I copied the question verbatim

Comment: Based on the diagram $\frac{C+E+D}{A+B+D+F+G}$

Comment: Got the Answew A=1,B=1

Comment: HENCE ratio is $\frac{\pi^2-2}{\pi^2+2}$

Comment: The $D$ areas do not cancel out because it is a ratio, not a difference.

Comment: Also WolframAlpha give no exact answer for the intersection.

Answer (score 1):

At least in the interval $[\pi/2,\pi]$, $-\operatorname{sgn}(x-\pi/2)\cos(x)=-\cos(x)$. The relation that defines the ellipse in the picture is
$$\frac{x^2}{\pi^2}+\frac{y^2}{2^2}=1$$
This can be solved for $y$ to obtain the equation for the upper part of the ellipse:
$$y=\sqrt{4\left(1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2}\right)}$$
Below is a diagram:
[image]

First we need to find the point of intersection of the curves by solving the below:
$$-\cos(x)=\sqrt{4\left(1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2}\right)}$$
This can be evaluated numerically to be $a\approx 2.77758115377641$
So our answer is
$$D=\int_{\pi/2}^{a}-\cos(x)\mathrm{d}x+\int_{a}^\pi \sqrt{4\left(1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2}\right)}\mathrm{d}x\approx  0.873512799654.$$
Then our area ratio is
$$\frac{2D+2A}{2\pi^2}$$
It can be easily verified that $A=1$ via the integral $\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(x)\mathrm{d}x=1$. Therefore,
$$\frac{0.873512799654+1}{\pi^2}\approx 0.18982653443$$